# Successful build with many errors in typescript typing files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2013 generating too many errors when building a web application with typescript definition files. For example consider the following scenario:

1. Start a new Empty Web Application
2. Right click on project and select Manage Nuget Packages
3. Add jquery and jquery typings (the typings I downloaded are a couple of days old)
4. Build the project
5. Project builds successfully with more than 100 errors (errors, not warnings), all in jquery.d.ts, like the following:

   - ',' expected.
   - '=' expected.
   - Identifier expected.

I get similar results when I do the same with angularjs instead of jquery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that you are using an older version of TypeScript than the definition author.

The language is moving swiftly and some of the features in version 1.4 are particularly useful in definition files, so it is likely that you will need to upgrade to 1.4 so that your machine can understand these new features.

[Download version 1.4 here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304).

Comment: You are absolutely right! That was it! I just assumed that since VS 2013 came with typescript, I would get notifications for typescript upgrades, just like I get for other things!

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem too, after opening the affected file, and being prompted to update the version of typescript used in my project...

Comment: I installed the latest Typescript via NuGet which is v2 and i still get hundreds of errors on jquery. How do I check which version of the compiler VS is using and how do I specify the right one??

Comment: @Dan open command prompt and run `tsc -v` if it doesn't show the latest version of TypeScript, check it is installed and check your PATH variable to make sure it points at the latest one. It installs to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`

Comment: @Steve so my path shows 1.0.3.0 which is location you said, but the nuget is 1.0.0.0 which is installed in packages (waste of time), so I should download 1.4 and install over SDK version i guess? Shame its not all automated!

Comment: @Dan 1.0.3 is an old version (that is TypeScript 1.1). You should update to 1.4 (stable) or 1.5 (beta). https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Comment: I was also getting these errors. if you install a different version of ts on an existing project, you also need to change the targeted version in your vs project file. see [updatestage.com/fix-wrong-typescript-version-error](http://updatestage.com/fix-wrong-typescript-version-error/) on how.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issues like this but I was able to resolve the jQuery issues by downgrading my DefinitelyTyped version of "1.0.1" instead of "1.4.1". Also I'm currently running on Mac and hopefully this can help users who are experiencing issues on Mac.

Comment: Downgrading would work do, but why downgrade the type definitions to match the old typescript instead of upgrade typescript to match the new definitions?

Comment: Not exactly sure why downgrading to 1.0.1 would solve this problem. Based from my understanding, the new version of the jquery.d.ts which pulls from the 1.4 DefinitelyTyped file uses syntax that is new to TypeScript 1.4, and there's a "1.3" branch on DefinitelyTyped specifically for pre-1.4-compatible files. If you happen to figure out the reasons whats causing this problem, please feel free to let me know. I was able resolve my issue based on this answer I got it from: http://quabr.com/28093877/latest-version-of-jquery-for-typescript-is-throwing-syntax-errors