# Unable to load interfaces of fabricjs.d.ts

Tags: typescript, fabricjs, definitelytyped

I am trying to load [fabricjs.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabricjs/fabricjs.d.ts) file in my project, after adding this i face two issues

1. text editor shows several errors in the file,
2. in visual studio intellisense i get only the functions and var defined in this d.ts file, i do not get the interfaces defined in the d.ts file.

Tried following:

- I am using 1.4 version of typescript
- changed visual studio project setting to  1.4
- While doing tsc -v it shows that i am using 1.4 version

also looked at [Successful build with many errors in typescript typing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086084/successful-build-with-many-errors-in-typescript-typing-files), but did not help.

**EDIT**

i tried installing [typescript 1.8.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739) and changed the project's typescript toolversion to 1.8.5, did not help, and yes tsc -v shows 1.8.5. The file still shows several errors(please refer to screenshot) in VS, though first 5-6 interface started appearing, but once i get the error at last member of interface then interfaces below that interface does not appear in visual studio intellisense. Please not in below screenshot we get IObservable as part of intellisense but do not get ICanvasAnimation.

[image]

Also tried installing [nuget 1.8.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.TypeScript/1.8.9), changed the probject file, still did not help. Also followed [this](http://www.allenconway.net/2015/07/which-version-of-typescript-is.html) post.

Answer (score 0):

> tsc -v it shows that i am using 1.4 version

That is a **really old version of tsc**. DefinitelyTyped only keeps support for TypeScript latest (for a variety of reasons).

You can go back to an old ts version manually if you want (but ofcourse definition quality will not be as good as the latest version) :

[image]

Comment: i have updated the issue with the findings please have a look.